# ¿Qué significados tiene «ya» al decir "deambulaba sin saber *ya* muy bien..." y "¡*ya* está aquí!"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, adverbios

No comprendo muy bien qué significan los dos «ya» aquí:

> Deambulaba por todas partes, sin saber **ya** muy bien en qué aldeas había estado y en cuáles no. A menudo, al aproximarme a algún pueblo, oía a los niños gritar: —¡**Ya** está aquí el bostezón!

¿Qué función hacen?

Comment: ¿Qué piensas que significa *ya* normalmente y por qué no piensas que *ya* tiene este significado en estas oraciones?  Y ¿cuál es tu idioma nativo?, que  tal vez podamos ayudarte mejor sabiéndolo.

Comment: Soy china. Siempre pienso “ya” = “already”. Pero creo que no sea adecuedo si pienso así aquí.

Comment: @Fabiola Sí; lo puedes entender así en este caso.

Comment: @Ustanak significa “already” en ambos casos? Pero no es que hay dicho como enfático o impresión de lamentar para “ya”?

Comment: @Fabiola "Ya" se puede entender como "anteriormente" o "ahora mismo".

Comment: @Ustanak Igual a “Deambulaba por todas partes, sin saber anteriormente (ya) muy bien en qué aldeas había estado y en cuáles no. A menudo, al aproximarme a algún pueblo, oía a los niños gritar: —¡Ahora mismo (Ya) está aquí el bostezón!” ??

Comment: Creo que seria buena mira la RAE un poco: http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=c8KthXc

Comment: @Lambie gracias. Lo he había mirado algunas veces. No he entendido mucho. Entonces ahora quiero que practicar.

Comment: En todo caso, no estoy de acuerdo en traducir hacia el inglés. Te sugiro mirar cada frase de la RAE y traducirlas a tu proprio idioma. Con la ayuda de: https://www.chino-china.com/diccionario

Answer (score 2):

> Deambulaba por todas partes, sin saber **ya** muy bien en qué aldeas había estado y en cuáles no.

Here it means "anymore": Without knowing it well anymore.

> A menudo, al aproximarme a algún pueblo, oía a los niños gritar: —¡**Ya** está aquí el bostezón!

In this case, 'ya' means already: The yawning is here already
In the sense of "here it goes", "it's here **now**".